# Newly created Outlok event, format start date to include in email

Tags: outlook, power-automate

I want to create a Power Automate flow that sends an email when a new Outlook calendar event is created.  The email should have only the event's name and formatted start time in the subject line, as well as the formatted start time in the body.

I can't figure out how to **format** the date.  I have an Expression with a call to the formatDateTime function:

```
formatDateTime(@{triggerOutputs()?['body/start']}, 'm/d h:mm')
```

[image: workflow diagram]

But I get a message that the expression is invalid.

[image: error message]

Would really appreciate some help on what I need to do differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested because I can’t see the exact payload you’re working with but change this ...

```
formatDateTime(@{triggerOutputs()?['body/start']}, 'm/d h:mm')
```

... to this ...

```
formatDateTime(triggerOutputs()?['body/start'], 'm/d h:mm')
```

Comment: Worked great, thank you! I'd been killing myself trying to read the documentation, really appreciate your help.